# Storing images on the blockchain

Tags: blockchain

What is the best blockchain platform to store images on it for a blockchain application that stores images and can be retrieved easily or changed?

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to store images on the blockchain. Although some DLT platforms, such as Highperleger Fabric and Corda, support the storage and transfer of rather large pieces of data, the general principle of storing images and, in general, large files is the following.The file is saved either in a decentralized file system (Ipfs, Ethereum Swarm, Storj and so on), or in cloud storage, or on a web resource. Further, the link to the file and its hash (to control the integrity and exclude substitution) are sent to the blockchain.